# How to groupby an xarray dataarray along a dimension and multiply/add with the corresponding coordinate values?

Tags: python-xarray

Lets say I have a DataArray

```
da = xr.DataArray(
    np.random.randint(0,10, (5,5),
    coords={'x':[1,2,3,4,5], 'y':[1,2,3,4,5]},
)
```

I want to groupby 'x' and multiply each group with 1 or 2 or 3 etc.

What is the shortest and clearest way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr


da = xr.DataArray(
    np.random.randint(0, 10, (5, 5)),
    coords={'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'y': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]},
)

# Group by 'x' and multiply each group with corresponding values
multiplier = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  # You can adjust these values as needed
result = da.groupby('x') * xr.DataArray(multiplier, coords=[da['x']], dims='x')
```

The resulting DataArray will have the same dimensions as the original one and will contain the multiplied values for each group.